# If radio button not checked, display all rows from column - formulating sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form with text fields and radio buttons, used to make search queries in an SQL database. The form has radio buttons, and when not selected, they would cause an undefined variable error. I've temporarily solved it by having a radio button checked at default, but that's not a good solution.

If a radio button is not checked, I'd like the search result to display all rows from the column the variable represents.

I think my PHP solution might be functional:

```
  if (!isset($POST_['difficulty'])) {
            $difficulty = '*';
        }
        else {
            $difficulty = $POST_['difficulty'];
        }
```

However, I am struggling to get the SQL query correctly. Currently, it looks like this:

```
$query = "Select * FROM Questions WHERE question LIKE '%$question%' AND category LIKE '%$category%' AND subcategory LIKE '%$sub_category%' AND Difficulty LIKE '%$difficulty%' AND UsedBefore LIKE '%$usedbefore%' AND knockout LIKE '%$knockout%'";
```

Essentially, I want to formulate an SQL query, so that if the radio button is not selected, the inserted variable would make the query select all rows from that column.

Right now, though, if the radio-button is unchecked, $difficulty would be replaced by `*`, but the query `"Difficulty LIKE '%*%'"` does not work.

**tldr; How can I formulate an SQL query, so that if a radio-button is unchecked, the replaced variable ("difficulty") would correctly get all rows from a specific column?**

This is my full code:

**Front-end PHP:**

```
<form action="Search.php" method="post">
    <div class="container_search_criteria">
        <label>Quizspørsmål</label> <input type="text" id="search-question" name="question" title="Quizsspørsmål" placeholder="Søk etter spørsmål" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['question'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['question']);}?>">
        <label>Kategori:</label> <select name="category"> 
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Finkultur'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Finkultur">Finkultur</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Geografi'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Geografi">Geografi</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Historie'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Historie">Historie</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Livsstil'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Livsstil">Livsstil</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Natur & Vitenskap'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Natur & Vitenskap">Natur & Vitenskap</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Populærkultur'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Populærkultur">Populærkultur</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Samfunnsfag'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Samfunnsfag">Samfunnsfag</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == 'Sport & Spill'){  echo "Selected";} ?> value="Sport & Spill">Sport & Spill</option>
        </select>
            <label>Sub-kategori</label><input type="text" name="subcategory" class="subcat" id="add-subcategori" title="Sub-kategori" placeholder="Legg til sub-kategori" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subcategory'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['subcategory']);}?>">
            <label>Vanskelighetsgrad: </label>
                <ul class="difficulty">
                <li>Enkel</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="1"></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="2"></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="3" checked="checked"></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="4"></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="5"></li>

                <li>Vanskelig</li>
                </ul>
            <label>Har du brukt spørsmålet før?</label>
                <ul class="usedbefore">
                <li><input type="radio" name="usedbefore" value="Ja"></li>
                <li>Ja</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="usedbefore" value="Nei" checked="checked"></li>
                <li>Nei</li>
                </ul>
             <label>Hvis ja:</label>
                <ul class="details_usedbefore">
                    <li>Sted</li>
                    <li><input type="text" class="input_usedbefore" name="search-place" id="search-place" title="Sted brukt før" placeholder="Legg til sted"></li>
                    <li>Dato</li>
                    <li><input type="date" class="input_usedbefore" name="search-date"  id="search-date" title="Dato brukt før"></li>
                </ul>
            <label>Utslagsspørsmål?</label>
            <ul class="usedbefore">
                <li><input type="radio" name="knockout" value="Ja"></li>
                <li>Ja</li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="knockout" value="Nei" checked="checked"></li>
                <li>Nei</li>
            </ul>
            
                <button name="submit" class="search_button" id="main_button">Søk</button>
                <button type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="search_button" id="secondary_button" onClick="location.href='index.php'" >Avbryt</button>
```

**Backend PHP:**

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


include_once 'dbh_local.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $sub_category = $_POST['subcategory'];
    $usedbefore = $_POST['usedbefore'];
    $difficulty = $_POST['difficulty'];
    $knockout = $_POST['knockout'];

        if (!isset($POST_['difficulty'])) {
            $difficulty = '*';
        }
        else {
            $difficulty = $POST_['difficulty'];
        }

        if ($question != "" or $category != "" or $sub_category != "" or $usedbefore != "" ) {
           $query = "Select * FROM Questions WHERE question LIKE '%$question%' AND category LIKE '%$category%' AND subcategory LIKE '%$sub_category%' AND Difficulty LIKE '%$difficulty%' AND UsedBefore LIKE '%$usedbefore%' AND knockout LIKE '%$knockout%'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($count > 0) {
                echo '<table>';
                echo '<th>' . 'Spørsmål' . '</th>';
                echo '<th>' . 'Kategori' . '</th>';
                echo '<th>' . 'Subkategori' . '</th>';
                echo '<th>' . 'Vanskelighet' . '</th>';
                echo '<th>' . 'Brukt før?' . '</th>';
                
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $question = $row ['question'];
                    $category = $row ['category'];
                    $sub_category = $row ['subcategory'];
                    $difficulty = $row['Difficulty'];
                    $usedbefore = $row['UsedBefore'];
                ?>

            <tr class="RowLink">
                <td><?php echo $question;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $category;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $sub_category;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $difficulty; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usedbefore;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            
            echo '</table>';

            }
         
        else {
            echo "<div class = 'NoResult'>" . 'Beklager, jeg fant ingen spørsmål som passet det du søkte etter.' . "</div>"; 
        }
    }
}
            ?>
```

Comment: Why not remove the conditions that you don't want to apply?

Comment: For the database and the SQL, that would work, but PHP would throw an undefined variable error. Therefore, the variable has to be defined as something to avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Dharman. It's for a personal project, so I think I will be fine, but as you rightly point out, there is always the risk of corrupting my own data. I will certainly look into it

Comment: No, you are not fine. This is a serious bug which you need to fix ASAP. Stop what you are doing right now fix this major problem and then if your issue is still not resolved come back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code to use named parameters abd PDO instead of mysqli. It isnpt tested and may have dome typos, so take a look before running it.

Also, you'll find your code below and commented out.

```
<?php
//  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


include_once 'dbh_local.php';   //  See line 39 below. You may want to muve it, and the definition of the $options array into this file.

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $question = '%'.$_POST['question'].'%';
    $category = '%'.$_POST['category'].'%';
    $sub_category = '%'.$_POST['subcategory'].'%';
    $usedbefore = '%'.$_POST['usedbefore'].'%';
    $difficulty = '%'.$_POST['difficulty'].'%';
    $knockout = '%'.$_POST['knockout'].'%';

    if (!isset($POST_['difficulty'])) {
        $difficulty = '%';
    }
    if ($question != "" or $category != "" or $sub_category != "" or $usedbefore != "" ) {
        //  NOTE: notice that there are no quotes around the values. PDO will properly quote the values, and escape any characters as needed.
        $query = "Select * FROM Questions 
            WHERE question LIKE :question
            AND category LIKE :category
            AND subcategory LIKE :sub_category
            AND Difficulty LIKE 'difficulty 
            AND UsedBefore LIKE :usedbefore 
            AND knockout LIKE :knockout;";
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES  => false,                   // turn off emulation mode for 'real' prepared statements
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE           => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,  //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,       //make the default fetch be an associative array
        ];
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "username", "password", $options);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            echo 'Failed to connect to database.'; //something a user can understand
        }
        $has_rows = true;
        try {
            $result = $pdo->execute(array(':question' => $question,
                ':category' => $category,
                ':sub_caztegory' => $sub_category,
                ':difficulty' => $difficulty,
                ':usedbefore' => $usedbefore,
                ':knockout' => $knockout));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            $has_rows = false;
        }
        
        if($has_rows === true) {
            echo '<table>';
            echo "<tr>"
            echo '<th>' . 'Spørsmål' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Kategori' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Subkategori' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Vanskelighet' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Brukt før?' . '</th>';
            echo "</tr>"
    ?>
            foreach($result as $key =$row) {
            <tr class="RowLink">
                <td><?php echo $row['question'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['category;']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sub_category'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['difficulty']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['usedbefore']; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
            }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo "<div class = 'NoResult'>" . 'Beklager, jeg fant ingen spørsmål som passet det du søkte etter.' . "</div>"; 
        }
/*
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count > 0) {
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Spørsmål' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Kategori' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Subkategori' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Vanskelighet' . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . 'Brukt før?' . '</th>';
            
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $question = $row ['question'];
                $category = $row ['category'];
                $sub_category = $row ['subcategory'];
                $difficulty = $row['Difficulty'];
                $usedbefore = $row['UsedBefore'];
            ?>

        <tr class="RowLink">
            <td><?php echo $question;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sub_category;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $difficulty; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $usedbefore;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo "<div class = 'NoResult'>" . 'Beklager, jeg fant ingen spørsmål som passet det du søkte etter.' . "</div>"; 
        }
*/
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Sloan, thank you so much for taking the time to write out a solution! I'm not familiar with PDO, and so I'll try to come up with a procedural solution, but this is great inspiration and a good solution to fall back on.

Comment: PDO can be procedural, as it is my code above. You can also use parameterized queries in mysqli, it's just that they are a little more difficult to maintain IMHO. I strongly suggest you start to build good habits/skills and **always use parameterized queries**, and don't view them as _something to fall back on_. Trust me, as someone who's been burned, the easier path comes from building  good habits.